# Spray Pass a Scala Value to a Resource

Tags: scala, spray

I am trying to use Spray to fulfill my routing needs for a Scala based web application. I'm wondering how you can pass a Scala val to a front end resource, such as using a variable inside an HTML file. What is the appropriate way to accomplish this? (If this is possible)

My current route code:

```
val indexRoute =
  get {
    path("") {
      val name = "hello"
      getFromResource("views/index.html")
    }
}
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <h1>{name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This obviously just ends up printing out {name} on the page

I know I can do something like:

```
val indexRoute = {
  get {
    path("") {
      val name = "hello"
      complete {
        <html>
          <body>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
          </body>
        </html>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am hoping there is a way to separate the views from the routing logic itself and into their own files. Is this doable or will I need to define HTML inside the routes?

Comment: Spray doesn't really have a presentation layer like you are using.  It's usually used to provide a REST API.  Have you looked at the Play! Framework?  It has a templating engine that works like what you want.

Comment: +1 for Play framework if you need template engine to build UI

Comment: Thanks, I've used play, was hoping for something more lightweight. Perhaps Spray is not the right decision though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use [Twirl](https://github.com/spray/twirl) for you needs.

A short example that's taken from the github page examples

```
@(name: String, age: Int = 42)
<html>
@* This template is a simple html template --- (this text btw. is a comment and is not rendered) *@
<h1>Welcome @name!!</h1>
<p>You are @age years old, @(if(age < 21) <i>shouldn't you be in bed ?!</i> else <i>have a great      evening !</i>)</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I had no idea they had pulled this out of Play

Comment: It was actually pulled from spray into Play, and then also maintained as a standalone piece, which can again be used in spray.